# Can you help me point out why other tasks (apart from the unzip_data task) are not running?

Tags: python, airflow, etl

So, I'm new to ETL pipelines and I'm trying to create a dag. The dag starts fine and the first task (`unzip_data`) runs but the rest fail to run. Can you help me point out why?
Below is the full code:

```
# importing required libraries
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

#defining the DAG arguments

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Ogbonna Jackson',
    'start_date': days_ago(0),
    'email': ['jacksonianville1590@yahoo.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

#dag definition
with DAG(
    'ETL_toll_data',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Apache Airflow Final Assignment',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
) as dag:

    #define tasks
    #---------------------------

    unzip_data = BashOperator(
        task_id='unzip_data',
        bash_command='tar -zxvf /home/thetruejacksonian/airtest/air/tolldata.tgz',
        dag=dag,
    )


    extract_data_from_csv = BashOperator(
        task_id='extract_data_from_csv',
        bash_command='cut -d"," -f 1-4 /home/thetruejacksonian/airtest/air/vehicle-data.csv > /home/thetruejacksonian/airtest/air/airstage/staging/csv_data.csv',
        dag=dag,
    )

    extract_data_from_tsv = BashOperator(
        task_id='extract_data_from_tsv',
        bash_command='cut -f 5-7 /home/thetruejacksonian/airtest/air/tollplaza-data.tsv > /home/thetruejacksonian/airtest/air/airstage/tsv_data.csv --output-delimiter=","',
        dag=dag,
    )

    extract_data_from_fixed_width = BashOperator(
        task_id='extract_data_from_fixed_width',
        bash_command='cut -c 59-61,63-68 /home/thetruejacksonian/airtest/air/payment-data.txt > /home/thetruejacksonian/airtest/air/airstage/fixed_width_data.csv --output-delimiter=","',
        dag=dag,
    )

    consolidate_data = BashOperator(
        task_id='consolidate_data',
        bash_command='paste /home/thetruejacksonian/airtest/air/airstage/csv_data.csv /home/thetruejacksonian/airtest/air/airstage/tsv_data.csv /home/thetruejacksonian/airtest/air/airstage/fixed_width_data.csv > /home/thetruejacksonian/airtest/air/airstage/extracted_data.csv',
        dag=dag,
    )


    transform_data = BashOperator(
        task_id='transform_data',
        bash_command='awk \'BEGIN{FS=","; OFS=","} {print $1,$2,$3,toupper($4),$5,$6,$7,$8,$9}\' /home/thetruejacksonian/airtest/air/airstage/extracted_data.csv > /home/thetruejacksonian/airtest/air/airstage/transformed_data.csv',
        dag=dag,
    )

    #defining task pipeline

unzip_data >> extract_data_from_csv >> extract_data_from_tsv >> extract_data_from_fixed_width >> consolidate_data >> transform_data
```

when I run the command `airflow task test <dag name> <task name>` , I get the following similar error for each task

````
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thetruejacksonian/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1340, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context)
  File "/home/thetruejacksonian/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1477, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, self.task)
  File "/home/thetruejacksonian/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1538, in _execute_task
    result = execute_callable(context=context)
  File "/home/thetruejacksonian/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash.py", line 187, in execute
    raise AirflowException(
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code 1.```
````

Comment: If the first task is succeeding but the subsequent tasks are failing it could be because when you un-tar the folder it's creating a folder and not extracting the files as you are expecting. Have you tried running these commands one-by-one on the Airflow server to see what you get?

Comment: you're absolutely right @Simon D The first task appears to be successful in tests but does not actually extract the files

Answer (score 1):

Other tasks couldn't run due to the failure of the upstream (unzip data) task -which appears to run successfully but did not actually save the extracted files.
The code below was the problem
`'tar -zxvf /home/thetruejacksonian/airtest/air/tolldata.tgz',`

I had to save the extracted files by using this code, this was the solution:
`'tar -zxvf /home/thetruejacksonian/airtest/air/tolldata.tgz -C /home/thetruejacksonian/airtest/air',`